# Input pattern for password submits with empty input

Tags: forms, input

I have this pattern for html input password (UpperCase, LowerCase, Number/SpecialChar and min 8 Chars)

```
(?=^.{8,}$)((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$
```

**The form submits with an empty input, how can I prevent this from happening?**

Comment: You make the regex quite complicated. Can you explain what your regex aims to test. Is that necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<input type="password" required>` should work.